# Ajax - Getting Null Value if no new data

Tags: ajax, json, get, setinterval

I'm building a notification system and I'm just in need of one last part to make it work perfect.

When the ajax first loads it uses the php variable against the server side script to look for new content and if it does find something new it uses that new notification_id and updates the var for the next set of results, if it doesn't find anything the second time around the url notification_id becomes null and inserts null values into the div.

How would I stop this from happening?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var notification_id="<?php echo $notification['notification_id'] ;?>";
function loadIt() {

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "viewajax.php?notification_id="+notification_id,   
global: true,
dataType:"json",
cache: false,
success: function(data){
if(notification_id < data.notification_id){
 $("#notif_actual_text-"+data.notification_id).prepend('<div class="notif_ui"><div class="notif_text"><div  id="notif_actual_text-'+data['notification_id']+'" class="notif_actual_text"><img border=\"1\" src=\"userimages/cropped'+data['notification_triggeredby']+'.jpg\" onerror=this.src=\"userimages/no_profile_img.jpeg\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ><br /><a href="'+data['notification_id']+'">'+data['notification_content']+' </a><br />'+data['notification_time']+'<br /></div></div></div></div>');
 i = parseInt($("#mes").text()); $("#mes").text((i+data.num)); 
    }
notification_id = data.notification_id; 
}
});
}
setInterval(loadIt, 10000);              
 </script>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$notification['notification_id']`?

Maybe it isn't set

Comment: It is set as it loads the first time, then the second time it looks for the new value with `notification_id = data.notification_id;` but if there is no new value I want it to just use the original value and not be null!

Comment: Are you using a framework? or just plain php?

Comment: I'm using just plain php, built from the ground upwards.I'm pretty sure I need something to say.. `if(data!=='null')` start the ajax again else insert new data into div.

Comment: Only I'm not that up on ajax as I am php so I'll admit. I don't know what to do.

Comment: That code you posted, is it from viewajax.php?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if the code above is from viewajax.php):

```
// Simply use isset() to check if $_GET['notification_id'] is set or not
var notification_id="<?php echo isset($_GET['notification_id']) ? $_GET['notification_id'] : $notification['notification_id']; ?>";
```

or if you are sending it to another file:

```
<?php
  // Let's just say that this is viewajax.php
  $notification_id = $_GET['notification_id'];
  echo json_encode(array("notification_id" => $notification_id));
?>
```

Comment: No its from the client side.if it was viewajax there certainly wouldn't be an ajax function in there looking for viewajax.php